# R - Create presence/absence df

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame similar to the following:

```
Species<-c("a","b","c","d")
Samples<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

species<-sample(Species,20,replace=TRUE)

samples=sample(Samples,20,replace=TRUE)

df <- data.frame(samples,species)
```

I´d like to transform it in a `data.frame` where each species would appear as a column and each sample would occupy a single line. Values (0 and 1) would indicate presence and absence. My original `data.frame` has approx. 600k lines, 60k samples and 20 variables (species).

Comment: You're probably either looking for `model.matrix` or `table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
> reshape2::dcast(df,formula = samples ~ species)

      samples a b c d
    1       1 0 0 1 3
    2       2 0 3 1 0
    3       3 2 1 0 1
    4       4 0 1 0 1
    5       5 1 1 2 1
    6       6 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: @Dominic Comtois It worked, thank you. 

Ananda, I guess this would complement it, right?

df<-1*(df>0)

Comment: Np! I missed the 0-1 only part thogh. Just be careful with the samples column if you use df>0 trick, since them too will become 1's!

Comment: OK, I see. It worked for me because in the data.frame I´m working with columns will always have 1 or 0. This is because a sample with a certain specie will never appear more than once.

Answer (score 1):

As Ananda already mentioned in the comments, you could use `table`, for example:

```
as.data.frame(with(df, table(samples, species)) > 0L) +0L
#  a b c d
#1 1 0 1 1
#2 1 1 0 1
#3 1 0 1 0
#4 1 1 1 1
#5 1 0 0 1
#6 0 1 1 0
```

The data I used here is:

```
Species <- c("a","b","c","d")
Samples <- 1:6
set.seed(99)
df <- data.frame(samples = sample(Samples, 20, replace=TRUE), 
                 species = sample(Species, 20, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: I guess you could simplify it to just `as.data.frame((table(df) > 0L) + 0L)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, true for the sample data, but in case the real data.frame contains more than those 2 columns, it would be required to call the columns explicitly.

Comment: Both ways worked fine for me. The only difference is that without calling the columns explicitly the samples don´t become variables, while in the method proposed by @beginnerR they do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Very welcome, @Gil33. Btw, you can say thanks by upvoting answers if they are helpful.